# How to convert File to Byte array in Android that can be consumed in ASP.Net (SOAP) Web Service?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, soap, arrays

i have a simple file upload web service in ASP.net (SOAP), here's is the code :

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function UploadFile(ByVal f As Byte(), ByVal fileName As String) As String
        Dim result As String = Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New Result("INFO"))
        Dim ms As MemoryStream
        Dim fs As FileStream

        Try
            ms = New MemoryStream(f)
            fs = New FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Upload/") & fileName, FileMode.Create)

            ms.WriteTo(fs)

            result = Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New Result("Upload Successful", ""))
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(New Result("Upload Failed", ex.Message))
            MyCustomClass.Utilities.EventsLog.CreateEventsLog("FileDALC.asmx - UploadFile", ex.Message, ex.Source, "Services", Utilities.EventsLogType.Failed)
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(ms) Then
                ms.Close()
                ms.Dispose()
            End If 

            If Not IsNothing(fs) Then
                fs.Close()
                fs.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try 

        Return Result
    End Function
```

All i want is to call that web service from my Android device and send some byte array parameter, but i always failed to produce byte array that can be recognized by web service..

Here's my code in Android device:

```
public class WebServiceUploadData {
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://services.chameleonmobile.app/"; 
    private static String URL = "http://10.41.25.49/SERVICES/Chameleon.WS.TitaniumMobile/FileDALC.asmx";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://services.chameleonmobile.app/";

    public static String invokeUploadFile(byte[] _file, String _fileName, String webMethName) {
        String resTxt = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

        PropertyInfo file = new PropertyInfo();
        file.setName("f");
        file.setValue(_file);

        PropertyInfo fileName = new PropertyInfo();
        fileName.setName("fileName");
        fileName.setValue(_fileName);
        fileName.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(file);
        request.addProperty(fileName);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resTxt = response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            if (e.getMessage().contains("EHOSTUNREACH")){
                 resTxt += "Error occured (Method Not Found, Wrong Network) - " + e.getMessage();
            }
            else if(e.getMessage().contains("ENETUNREACH")){
                resTxt += "Error occured (Network Offline and Unreachable) - " + e.getMessage();
            }
            else{
                resTxt += "Error occured - " + e.getMessage();
            }   
        } 

        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

And call that function in MainActivity.java asynchronously..

i produce the byte array like this (uploadFile is byte array parameter that will be send to web service):

```
File dirFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TempDownloadFile", "Halo.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dirFile);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
}                      
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
uploadFile = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and also try this :

```
byte[] uploadData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(dirFile);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array
uploadFile = Base64.encode(uploadData, Base64.DEFAULT);//Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

and this:

```
uploadFile = Base64.encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But unfortunately, all methods that i've tried is not working for me and my soap web service still can't recoqnize my byte array..

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using something like Fiddler to record the traffic that's hitting your Web Service, so that you can see what the soap request actually looks like and post that.

I'd also consider not concatenating together taken from the Internet, since that puts your server at risk, via a technique known as directory traversal attack:

```
Dim badFileName As String = "..\..\inetpub\wwwroot\default.aspx"
File.CreateText("C:\Users\a-h\" + badFileName)
```

That snippet of code, which is similar to your code, will attempt to create a file at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\default.aspx, not the C:\Users\a-h\ directory I was expecting to save it to.

Finally, perhaps you might find using the Web API easier from Android, since you can just post a HTTP request instead.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your answer.. It's okay i think, since this server is private server, not public server over internet.. Do you know how to create byte arrayfor my file from android? so i can send them through my web service.. thanks :D

Comment: Did you try the fiddler suggestion?

Comment: You already have the code to create a byte array from a file in your example.             
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();